# What is the equivalent of IVisitor.CONTINUE TRAVERSAL in wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket, porting

I'm porting our Wicket 1.4 app to Wicket 1.5. Visitors are now [very different](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-Visitors). What I would like to know is how do I handle a CONTINUAL_TRAVERSAL in Wicket 1.5? The existing 1.4 code is below:

```
 public class MyFormVisitor implements IVisitor<Component, Object>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7271477325583441433L;
    private Set<Component> visited = new HashSet<Component>();

    @Override
    public Object component(Component c) {
        if (!visited.contains(c)) {
            visited.add(c);

            c.add(new MandatoryBehavior());
            c.add(new ErrorHighlightBehavior());
        }
        return IVisitor.CONTINUE_TRAVERSAL;
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert your method to something like this and you should be fine:

```
@Override
public void component(final Component c, final IVisit<Void> visit) {
    if (!visited.contains(c)) {
        visited.add(c);

        c.add(new MandatoryBehavior());
        c.add(new ErrorHighlightBehavior());
    }
}
```

As you can see in the documentation you linked, the traversal is now controlled via the [IVisit](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/util/visit/IVisit.html) passed to the method. If none of the methods to either stop or not go deeper is called, the traversal will simply continue.

Comment: Thanks DerMiggel. That's kind of what I thought but I couldn't find any verification in the documentation. You've done that for me, thanks again.